# Prevent word wrap after a hyphen in a man page

Tags: manpage

I have included the text `"c<change-num>"` in the DESCRIPTION section of a man page I am writing. Depending on the width of my terminal, the text is wrapped after the hyphen, like this:

```
   Blah blah blah blah blah blah "c<change-
   num>" blah blah blah...
```

How can I prevent the text wrapping after the hyphen, ensuring that `"c<change-num>"` is always displayed as a single word?

Answer (score 1):

From ["Writing manual pages"](http://liw.fi/manpages/) (emphasis mine):

> An unfortunate bit of arcane syntax is that dashes in options should
>   be prefixed by backslashes. Thus, write `\-\-bits`, not just `--bits`. The
>   Debian and Ubuntu implementation of `man` treats them the same, for
>   terminal output, but this is not portable. Technically a naked `-` means
>   a hyphen, whereas `\-` means a minus sign. Typographically these are
>   distinct, and they are also distinct in Unicode. **The typesetter is
>   free to break a line at a hyphen, but not at a minus.** For dashes in
>   options, you should thus use minuses, but in normal text, for normal
>   words, the hyphen.

So `"c<change-num>"` contains a hyphen, and the typesetter can break the line there.

`"c<change\-num>"` instead contains a minus, and the typesetter will not break the line there.